# ConcurrentHashMap: Need for synchronization when storing a collection as value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I have some code that uses `ConcurrentHashMap` and wanted to confirm whatever I am doing is correct or not.

The map stores String as key and a collection (`Set`) as value. I initially had an implementation where I would use lock striping pattern for doing some operations atomically (put, remove, etc.) but then realized that instead of that I can use the `computeIfAbsent/putIfAbsent` (for put) and `computeIfAbsent` (for remove). Multiple threads call all 4 methods (get, put, removeKey, removeValue).

Can anyone tell me if my AFTER code is correct and thread-safe? Thanks in advance!

```java
private final ConcurrentMap<K, Set<V>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private final ConcurrentMap<K, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public Set<V> getValue(K key) {
    if (map.get(key) == null) return null;
    return map.get(key).stream().map(k -> k.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

**BEFORE**

```java
private void putValue(K key, V value) {
        Object lock = locks.putIfAbsent(key, new Object());
    if (lock == null) lock = locks.get(key);
        Set<V> existingSet = map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {
            Set<V> values = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(MY_COMPARATOR);
            values.add(value);
            return values;
        });
        if (existingSet != null) { // <- my guess is that this is unnecessary
            synchronized (lock) {
                map.get(key).add(expiringValue);
            }
        }
    }

public void removeKey(K key) {
    if (key == null) return;
    if (map.get(key) != null) {
        Object lock = locks.get(key);
        synchronized (lock) {
            map.remove(key);
        }
        locks.remove(key);
    }
}

public void removeValue(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null || value == null) return;
    if (map.get(key) != null) {
        Object lock = locks.get(key);
        synchronized (lock) {
            map.get(key).remove(value);
            if (map.get(key).size() == 0) {
                map.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AFTER**

```java
private void putValue(K key, V value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(MY_COMPARATOR)).add(value);
}

public void removeKey(K key) {
    map.remove(key);
}

public void removeValue(K key, V value) {
    Set<ExpiringValue<V>> resultingValues = map.computeIfPresent(key, (k, values) -> {
        values.remove(value);
        return values;
    });
    if (resultingValues != null && resultingValues.size() == 0) {
        map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `computeIfAbsent` to initialize collection value if not yet present is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

At least one possible problem is that you can lose values with your `putValue`. The `computeIfAbsent` is thread-safe, but the `add()` is not anymore. Therefore you can (depending on your logic) come up with the following scenario:

```
T1: computeIfAbsent creates the set for key K
T2: removes K
T1: performs add on the set, which is no longer in the map
```

Comment: This is the right observation. I didn't pick up on the fact the set was being removed from the map as well.

Comment: So what if `T2` removes `K`, before or after `T1` adds value to the set? In either case the set *will* have the value, the map *will not* have a `K` key, so the set is unreachable (unless referenced elsewhere). --- I'm not saying there aren't problems with separation of `computeIfAbsent()` and `add()`, but the scenario you described is not it.

Comment: @Andreas it may not be a problem in the grand scheme of things. It's still a lost update, and depending on the actual code it can be an issue. At least it means that `putValue` is not atomic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most stable you could do is like this:

```
private void putValue(K key, V value) {
    map.compute(key, (k, values) -> {
        if (values == null) {
            values = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(MY_COMPARATOR);
        }
        values.add(value);
        return values;
    });
}

public void removeKey(K key) {
    map.remove(key); // No change.
}

public void removeValue(K key, V value) {
    map.computeIfPresent(key, (k, values) -> {
        values.remove(value);
        return values.isEmpty() ? null : values;
    });
}
```

Those guarantee that all actions are atomic. The use of [`compute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) in `putValue` feels a little clunky, but `ConcurrentHashMap` guarantees the behavior, so it's whatever.

The remapping function returning `null` in [`computeIfPresent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) is just the correct way to do what you were already trying to do:

> If the function returns `null`, the mapping is removed.

Comment: "The remapping function returning null in computeIfPresent is just the correct way to do what you were already trying to do" - I completely missed this fact.